# Why This Command's Output Is Different Between Sh and Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, xorg

I am trying to run the following if statement in Bash (to determine if Xorg is running or not):

```
if ! xset q &>/dev/null; then echo Yes; fi
```

Which prints nothing when I run it under Bash. However, if I run it under sh, it gives me a "Yes" and other output related to xset.

How could it be possible that an if statement output is different between the two? And is there a way to fix it on Sh?

Comment: try `if ! xset q >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then echo Yes; fi`. I don't believe `sh` supports the `&>` shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&>` is not a valid redirection in sh. `&` sends the command `xset q` to background use `if ! xset q >/dev/null 2>&1;then echo 'test'; fi;`